# Image transformation with Keras and Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I want to feed a network with images using Keras. I am downloading images from internet and  storing them into a numpy array. When I plot a single image then it is shown correctly.
As a next step I am creating a new numpy array in which I store the single image. However, at that step the image is only displayed as a black images. I wondering why this happens?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import urllib.request
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from keras import backend as K
%matplotlib inline

file = "http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1353/1230897342_2bd7c7569f.jpg"

# Read web file
images_or = np.ndarray((1,128, 128,3), dtype=np.uint8)
req = urllib.request.urlopen(file)
arr = np.asarray(bytearray(req.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
img = cv2.imdecode(arr,-1) # 'load it as it is'
images_or[0] = cv2.resize(img,(128,128))  

# Display image
plt.imshow(images_or[0])
plt.show()

# Format image
images_or = images_or.astype(K.floatx())
images_or *= 0.96/255
images_or += 0.02

# Display image
plt.imshow(images_or[0])
plt.show()

# Reshape image
images_or = images_or.reshape(images_or.shape[0], 3, 128, 128)

# Copy image in another np.array
A_train_test = np.ndarray((1, 3, 128, 128), dtype=np.uint8)
A_train_test[0] = images_or[0]  

# Format image
A_train_test = A_train_test.astype(K.floatx())
A_train_test *= 0.96/255
A_train_test += 0.02

# Reshape image
A_train_test = A_train_test.reshape(A_train_test.shape[0], 128, 128, 3)
image_xxx = A_train_test[0]

plt.imshow(image_xxx)
plt.show()
```

Thank you very much in advance,
Andi

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change the order of commands:

```
# Copy image in another np.array
A_train_test = np.ndarray((1, 3, 128, 128), dtype=np.uint8)
A_train_test = A_train_test.astype(K.floatx())
A_train_test[0][:] = images_or[0][:]
```

Issues is solved.